# Wordpress - include taxonomy description in JSON/REST API request

Tags: php, json, wordpress, rest

I'm using the Wordpress Rest API to get JSON data for a custom post type that has a couple of custom taxonomies. Using the _embed flag with my request I can get the taxonomy data associated with each post but the taxonomy description is missing.

So this is the URL I use:
/wp-json/wp/v2/my-custom-type?_embed

That gives me all the post data and the taxonomy ID, value, slug, link and the name of the taxonomy itself. But the description is not included. Here's an example of the taxonomy data included for one post:

```
 {"id":82,"link":"http:\/\/localhost\/sandbox\/custom-tax\/2\/","name":"Foo","slug":"foo","taxonomy":"custom-tax","_links":{"self":[{"href":"http:\/\/localhost\/sandbox\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/custom-tax\/82"}],"collection":[{"href":"http:\/\/localhost\/sandbox\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/custom-tax"}
```

This doesn't seem to be related to the fact I'm using custom post types and custom taxonomies. When querying regular posts (using /wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed) the category description is also missing.

Does anyone know how I can include the taxonomy description for each post as well?

Comment: A quick & dirty way of fixing this I realized was to include 'modify' to the description parameter of the get_item_schema function in class-wp-rest-terms-controller.php. So in short, modify row 846 to this:      'context'      => array( 'view', 'embed', 'edit' ),

Comment: you can add register rest field in your theme function without need to modify wordpress core